# Drupal 7 - How do I take the data from a form field to display it somewhere else?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

Hi my question is very simple but I didn't find the answer on the internet, I want to know how I can take the data from a form field on drupal 7 and display it when submited on another form field?

**here is an exemple:** Let's say I entered my email on the input below and submited.
[image]

How can I redirect the page and take the email field datas I entered to display it on this other form ?
[image]

---

Any idea to create this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use form submit handler function and redirect to a url where you can render new form and pass your field value in that url. When you render new form get the field value of previous form from the url and use it in your new form field value.

Thanks